# AWS Lambda: AutoPublishAlias and provisioned concurrency conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I am trying to add provisioned concurrency to an serverless template lambda. I am running into conflicts within the stack.

What I want to do is to remove the `AutoPublishAlias`, enable provisioned concurrency, maintain the alias name and deploy.

```
  SomeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      AutoPublishAlias: live
      FunctionName: somefunction
      DeploymentPreference:
        Type: AllAtOnce
        Enabled: true
      Hooks:
        PostTraffic: !Ref PostTrafficHook
```

Provisioned Concurrency requires an [Alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-alias.html) or a [version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-version.html)

Since `AutoPublishAlias` automatically creates a `Version` and an `Alias`, I can't just add an `AWS::Serverless::Alias` like I did for another project.

So I've adjusted the template:

```
  SomeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: somefunction
      DeploymentPreference:
        Type: AllAtOnce
        Enabled: true
      Hooks:
        PostTraffic: !Ref PostTrafficHook

  SomeFunctionAlias:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref SomeFunction
      FunctionVersion: !GetAtt SomeFunction.Version
      Name: live

  SomeFunctionVersion:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref SomeFunction
      ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig:
        ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: 5
```

The issue I am having now is that the alias created from `AutoPublishAlias` still exists when trying to deploy the stack.

> Alias already exists: arn:aws:lambda:region:account:function:somefunction:live (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 409; Error Code: ResourceConflictException; Request ID: request-id)

I do not want to have to change the alias name to accommodate this change and everything should be able to handled by Cloudformation - e.g. I am not going to go through every instance of this and manually delete functions.

Any thoughts on how to accommodate this?